# Cloud load testing tool with crawl capability

Tags: performance, testing, cloud, jmeter, load-testing

I need to get a glance of pages that are bottlenecks on a certain website. I was trying to find a cloud load testing tool that would start from homepage and descend 1 level into all links, but I couldn't find such tool.
Basically, what I need is to insert URL, and the script then tests with like 10 or 20 users every page that is linked from the page I inserted. That would provide me with a basic view of load times for most pages on the website.

Anyone familiar with such a tool?
Closest thing I could find was jcrawl, but it requires installing jakarta ant, server configuration and what not, and I think what I need is pretty basic and shouldn't require several hours to be put into scripting and configuration.

Thanks

Comment: Added a cheeky jmeter tag to improve feedback

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve this using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) (JMeter is arguably the best free and open source load testing tool available). You could make one request and use a regular expression extractor to parse the response, pulling out any href values, and then have a loop which cycles through each url found.

Below is a JMeter testplan that does exactly what you want. Just copy this xml into a text file and save it as something.jmx. Open it in JMeter and change the demo hostname to YOUR OWN SITE (don't spam others, it's bad form). CTRL-R to run.

For more users (threads) or iterations (loops) just click on the Thread Group Name and change the values to what you need.

Very vague advice: Don't use more than, say, 300 threads on a single PC.

If you want to run this on 'the cloud' then rent an Amazon AWS machine, [install jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi), copy this jmx file onto it, and run it from the command line using:

`$ cd /to/where/jmeter/is/apache-blah/bin/`

`$ ./jmeter -n -t /path/to/my/testplan.jmx -l /where/to/put/results.jtl`

Demo Crawl Testplan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.3">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="crawl" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="HTTP Cookie Manager" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
        <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">false</boolProp>
      </CookieManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group Name" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">startnextloop</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1346172541000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1346172541000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="homepage" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">www.bbc.co.uk</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">enter YOUR SITE in the Server Name field</stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="urls" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">urls</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">&lt;a href=&quot;http:\/\/www.bbc.co.uk([^&quot;]+)&quot;</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default">NOTFOUND</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">-1</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <ConstantThroughputTimer guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="ConstantThroughputTimer" testname="Constant Throughput Timer" enabled="true">
            <doubleProp>
              <name>throughput</name>
              <value>6.0</value>
              <savedValue>0.0</savedValue>
            </doubleProp>
            <stringProp name="calcMode">this thread only</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Each thread makes 6 requests every minute (if it completes in time)</stringProp>
          </ConstantThroughputTimer>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <ForeachController guiclass="ForeachControlPanel" testclass="ForeachController" testname="ForEach Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.inputVal">urls</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.returnVal">url</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="ForeachController.useSeparator">true</boolProp>
        </ForeachController>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="foundUrl" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">www.bbc.co.uk</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">${url}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">enter YOUR SITE in the Server Name field</stringProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <GaussianRandomTimer guiclass="GaussianRandomTimerGui" testclass="GaussianRandomTimer" testname="Gaussian Random Timer" enabled="true">
              <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">300</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">500.0</stringProp>
            </GaussianRandomTimer>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <hostname>true</hostname>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="StatVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Aggregate Report" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <hostname>true</hostname>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, client hired a separate company to do the benchmarks in the mean time, but I'm sure this will do good to someone else looking for the same thing